# Regular expression matching from the end

Tags: c#, regex

start123start123

**start123endstart345end**

**start567endstart789end**

I need to extract a number of sets of data(bold) between all start and end of the above string.

My code:

```
Regex re = new Regex(start(.*)end, RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match m in re.Matches(text)) dosomething();
```

The only extracted text will be **789**

The problem is that I dont know the exact number of start and end formatted text needed to be extract. I want my regular expression to be able to ignore the start first two start only but greedy regex is ignoring all the start until the last one.

Can it be stopped after it matches the first end text?

If not, is there an option to matched the text from the back?

**Update:**

Actually, my original code is using non-greedy regex.

The extracted text will be **123start123\r\nstart123** , **345** , **567** , **789**

The newline parameter RegexOptions.Singleline is necessary in my real case, I am simplifying the case here for everyone  to understand easily

**Update 2:**

My expected output is **123** , **345** , **567** , **789**

Comment: try with non-greedy `(start(.*?)end)` what is expected output?

Comment: Updated, its not working

Comment: will it only digits between start & end?

Comment: @IsoletChan Post your expected output from those 3 strings please.

Comment: @SimonHalsey no, have to use wildcard. I just try to simplify the case for everyone to understand easily

Comment: I think your over-simplifications of your problem are making it hard for people to help you. Will `start` appear in the text again? Is it only ever the first 2 you want to ignore?

Comment: Yes, there are only two start text at the beginning. I will post my real case text next time. Sorry to make so many confusions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` is a **greedy** operator. Therefore, `.*` will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match.To get a [non-greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) match, use `*?`

```
start(.*?)end
```

### Edit

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use a **Negative Lookahead**. ( [Explanation](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3Fs%29start%28%28%3F%3A%28%3F%21start%29.%29*%29end&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) )

```
String s = @"start123start123
start123endstart345end
start567endstart789end";

Regex re = new Regex(@"(?s)start((?:(?!start).)*)end");

foreach (Match m in re.Matches(s))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output**

```
123
345
567
789
```

Comment: Its working! I am a noob, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: The negative lookahead looks ahead to see if there is not: `start` that follows, then matches any character(s) then `end`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get only the numbers between start and end excluding the words start & end ofcourse:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<=start)[0-9]*(?=end)");
string test = "start123endstart345end";
var resultings = reg.Matches(test);
```

It will get {1,2,3} {3,4,5} {5,6,7} {7,8,9} in the string you showed:

```
start123endstart345end

start567endstart789end
```

Comment: no i understood you you only want the numbers in the string which is what this will get you like i said above.

Comment: It works if the text is oneline text but its no extracted properly when it is multiline

Comment: @IsoletChan,it does,i try it myself.

Comment: I have to apologize again...My real case text is not just number and have to use wildcard, thats why i make so many confusions

Answer (score 1):

C# code to get only the numbers between the start and end strings,

```
{
String input = @"start123start123
start123endstart345end
start567endstart789end";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=start)\d+(?=end)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wI6fK3/2)

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/IYTkmM)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=start)\d+` Lookbehind is used to look just after to the a particular string which matches the pattern. In our case, it looks just after to the string `start`.
- `\d+(?=end)` Matches one or more digits which should be followed by the string `end`

Comment: It seems to extract the same text as the non-greedy version regex from the demo

Comment: i think it matches your requirement `The extracted text will be 123start123\r\nstart123 , 345 , 567 , 789`

Comment: I have to use wildcard to extract the text between. I will use my real case text next time when asking question. Sorry